# how do I add an alternate flash message after applying this class method in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is the class method in the model that I added into my Rails 3 code

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.without_review
    where(review: false)
  end
```

FYI, here's the schema.db showing "review"

```
 create_table "microposts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.boolean  "review",          :default => false
  end
```

All posts are defaulted to review=false, but if a user checkmarks a box right before create, then review=true.

This is the controller where the flash message is

```
  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Posted"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

I want the same behavior as how it is right now if review=false, but if review=true I want to flash a message that says "Post is under review" instead of "Posted"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make these changes on `create`

```
  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      if @micropost.review 
        # If review is true. The object @micropost is already built with necessary 
        # parameters sent by the form, say whether review is true.
        flash[:notice] = "Post is under review"
      else
        flash[:success] = "Posted"
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error in this controller with the above code. `unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end
unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end`. How many `end` should there be? I tried various different amounts but couldn't resolve the error

Comment: Forget to add `end` for if block, that's easy to spot. Revised.

Comment: any idea why I get a `Template is missing Missing template microposts/create` when I make a post with the checkbox checked which makes the post review=true?

Comment: @AmyBrown, I think you need to check your routes.rb. You may have defined `create` in `GET` by some auto generated code. Try set `resources :microposts` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Posted"
      flash[:success] = "Post is under review" if @micropost.review 
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = @micropost.review ? "Posted" : "Post is under review"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```